# Get 404's with MVC 5 Api controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Controller:

```
public class DownloadListController : ApiController
{
    private MovieService _movieService;

    public DownloadListController()
    {
        _movieService = new MovieService();
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]string asd)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public string Get()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
    // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
    // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
    //config.EnableQuerySupport();

    // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
    // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
    config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
}
```

When I run the application and browse to `http://localhost:4229/api/DownloadList` I get an 404, while I can see in the Network request being made is a `GET` request.

The same is also true when I make a `POST` request to a URI, the result is a 404.

What am I missing? What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Note: WebAPI is not MVC.  They are not "MVC 5 API controllers", they are WebAPI 2.x API controllers  It just so happens that WebAPI was introduced WITH MVC4, but it's a different set of technologies that works with MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web API doesn't use explicit actions. They are implied by the HTTP verbs. So you shouldn't have an `{action}` in your `routeTemplate`:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
```